# Animated Image Slider loop is not starting from the end point

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, css-animations

I have a very simple animated image slider. I want it to move from the right to the left infinitely. It contains 10 images. At the end of the 10th image, I want the image no. 1 to be reappeared again and then 2 and so on.

But the problem is after the end of the 10th image the first image reappears from the initial position which I don't want. I want it to be reappeared seamlessly after the 10th image and then the 2nd image and then the 3rd etc.

How can I achieve that? Any suggestion?

I have tried a lot of things like instead of applying the animation to the `ul` I applied it to the individual `li`s and also tried with different keyframe values (which I commented out). But I don't have enough CSS animation knowledge so these are just guesses without proper calculations or understanding.

Even if you can provide me a resource from where I can learn and then achieve it would be appreciated too.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/rakibul2010islam/pen/eYbybVb)

My codes:

```css
:root{
    --t: 10s;
}

ul{
    animation: move var(--t) linear infinite;
    display: flex;
}
            
ul:hover{
    animation-play-state: paused;
}

@keyframes move {
    /* 0% { transform: translate(-250%);} */
    100% {transform: translate(-150%)};
    /* 100% {transform: translate(-250%)};
    100% {transform: translate(-500%)}; */
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        1<img src="https://picsum.photos/400/600?random=1" width="400" height="600" alt="">                    
    </li>
    <li>
        2<img src="https://picsum.photos/400/600?random=2" width="400" height="600" alt="">                    
    </li>
    <li>
        3<img src="https://picsum.photos/400/600?random=3" width="400" height="600" alt="">                    
    </li>
    <li>
        4<img src="https://picsum.photos/400/600?random=4" width="400" height="600" alt="">                    
    </li>

    <li>
        5<img src="https://picsum.photos/400/600?random=5" width="400" height="600" alt="">                    
    </li>
    <li>
        6<img src="https://picsum.photos/400/600?random=6" width="400" height="600" alt="">                    
    </li>
    <li>
        7<img src="https://picsum.photos/400/600?random=7" width="400" height="600" alt="">                    
    </li>
    <li>
        8<img src="https://picsum.photos/400/600?random=8" width="400" height="600" alt="">                    
    </li>
    <li>
        9<img src="https://picsum.photos/400/600?random=9" width="400" height="600" alt="">                    
    </li>
    <li>
        10<img src="https://picsum.photos/400/600?random=10" width="400" height="600" alt="">                    
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: https://verpex.com/blog/website-tips/how-to-create-an-infinite-image-slider-using-css

Comment: I found this post before posting the question here and tried but was unable to apply it in my template. I think it is a good one though. Thanks for the recommendation :)